# mysql search 3 columns with dynamic count of words

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields. These fields are: name, surname, address. When I search by one word and any of fields contains the word, this row should be selected. When I search by 2 words 2 of 3 fields should have these words and so on. I have ready query in my hand.

This is for 2 word search string:

```
where (name like %word1% or surname like %word1% or address like %word1%) 
   and (name like %word2% or surname like %word2% or address like %word2%)
```

Number of intermediate `and`s = words - 1. `Where` part is generated depending on number of words in search string. How can I optimize this query?

Comment: You can't really. '%...' cannot use an index so unless you can address that, you're stuck

Comment: Can it be 2 columns contain word1 and no columns contain word2? Do they have to be different columns?

Comment: If you change `or` to `+` you'll get the count of columns that matched that word. You can compare that to your threshold.